# 2D Matrix declaration differences

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, vector, 2d

I noticed something strange about my code, and the amount of time it was taking to declare and initialize a 2D matrix of mine.

**First way**:

```
vector< vector<double> > gblStiff(dOF, vector<double>(dOF, 0));
```

dOF was some determined value earlier in the code. This first way took approximately **3 seconds when dOF = 30000!!**

**Second way**:

```
double** gblStiff = new double*[dOF];
for (i=0; i < dOF; i++) 
    gblStiff[i] = new double[dOF];
```

This second way takes **0.063 seconds for the same dOF!!**

Anyone able to shed light onto why this is happening? I am extremely curious.

Comment: A single contiguous buffer would be even faster.  Index it with `gblStiff[dOF*row + col]` (or the opposite, depending on your storage order and index definitions).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a C++ question.  First, you probably didn't compile with optimisation.  The `vector` template really needs a little compiler help to be usable.  Second, `vector`'s constructor initialises all of the elements; in your case, it initialises `dOF*dOF` `double`s to zero.  `new double[dOF]` does no such thing; that memory can contain anything at all.